# Storing and reading lists of lists in parquet

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, parquet

I'm storing a pandas dataframe with a column consisting of a list of lists in parquet. Something like

```py
import pandas as pd

values = [
    [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
    [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["lists"] = values
df.to_parquet("pq_file.parquet")
```

so far so good. The problem comes when with the data types once I read this data again

```py
df_read = pd.read_parquet("pq_file.parquet")
x = df_read["lists"][0]
x
```

this returns

```py
>>> array([array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

The first thing to notice is that the type of the column has changed from list to array. Also, the returned array it is not the standard type for numpy arrays. For instance if we do

```
y = np.array(values[0)
y
```

we get

```py
>>> array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4]])
```

Also, if we check the size of these arrays we get

```py
print(x.shape)
# (2,)
print(y.shape)
# (2, 2)
```

So the type and the shape of the `values` column after reading the parquet is not the one would expect. Also, having an array in this format completely defeats the purpose of having numpy arrays.

Otoh, I tried to build an array similar to `x` but I failed. I don't know how is parquet able to build such a weird object. Eg, if you try

```
np.array([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])])
```

you obtain

```
>>> array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4]])
```

and not

```
>>> array([array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

My question is then, how can I store nested arrays in parquet without getting this weird effects when reading them later?

Comment: The key thing to note is this `dtype=object`.  It is the array equivalent of a list.

Comment: In `np.array([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])])` `np.array` tries, and succeeds in making a 2d numeric dtype array.   But it is possubke ti make a (2,) object dtype array and fill it iwth arrays.  That's what `parquet` is doing.  I don't use `parquet` so can't say whether this 'nested' array as opposed to nested list approach starts with the dataframe, or if its a 'regular' part of `parquet`.  I suggested, in a another recent SO, to use `np.stack(x)` to create the 2d array.  In some cases `np.array(x.tolist())` might also work.

Comment: you might try to see if reading with engine=fastparquet changes the results.